# How to merge extended vertex?

Tags: modeling

I delete a one vertex from a plane and extend one of the vertices toward the open one by uisng magnet tool in *closest vertex* mode. I connected them with magnet tool. Is there a special command to merge two points when one is **extended vertex**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly clear on what the end result should be, but there are several ways to clean up extra vertices.

You can enable *Auto Merge Vertices* which will automatically clean up verts that are at the same location.

[image]

Then it is possible to <kbd>G</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> *Vertex Slide* along the edge and merge the two verts into one.

[image]

Or select both verts and use <kbd>M</kbd> -> *Merge at Center*.

[image]